# Corruption in uitable header when using setValue on the scrollbar

Tags: java, matlab, jscrollpane, matlab-uitable, visual-glitch

I am trying to create a table in MATLAB where I can change the scroll position programmatically. I created a `uitable` and extracted the handle of the Java `UITablePeer` object (designated here as `htable`).

I then got the handle for the `UIScrollbarPane` object using:

```
hscroll = htable.getParent.getParent.getVerticalScrollBar
```

At this point, the figure looks like this (my actual table is more complicated, this is just something I made as an example):

[image: before]

The box at the lower left corner of the table is a `pushbutton`. When its callback is triggered, it uses the `setValue` method to change the scrollbar location, e.g.

```
hscroll.setValue(10)
```

After this, the table looks like this:

[image: After]

As you can see, the top of the table becomes corrupted. I've tried using the `refresh` function or `repaint` method, but they don't seem to help; the only way to "fix" this is to move another window (by dragging or Alt-Tabbing)  such that the table is completely covered, and when I switch back to the table it's OK. Obviously, this isn't really an optimal solution.

Can anyone suggest a way to prevent or fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here is my implementation (adapted from [this code](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-listbox-editbox-scrollbars#comment-253396)):

```
% create a sample table with random data
figure('Menubar','none', 'Position',[400 400 250 300])
h = uitable('Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0 1 1], ...
    'ColumnName',{'1','2'}, 'Data',num2cell(rand(50,2)>0.5));

% get Java handles
jScroll = findjobj(h, 'class','UIScrollPane');
jView = jScroll.getViewport();
jTable = jView.getView();

% scroll to specified row (make it the top row)
row = 20 - 1;        % 20th row (zero-based index)
jView.setViewPosition(java.awt.Point(0, row * jTable.getRowHeight()))
jScroll.repaint()    % workaround for any visual glitches
```

The table is correctly displayed (no glitches) every time I tried it:

[image: scrolled_table]

Comment: Nice to see a working solution, though I am curious as to whether you have any suspicion of what is going wrong when the asker tries to do it in the way they mentioned.